# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am using $.ajax function in jquery.

I have written the following code:

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {

        var id =%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%;

                   var AllData="" ;
        $.ajax({


            url: "http://xtremeinspection.com/new2you4kids/app/android/get_product_size.php?productID=48",

            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: (function(data) {

                 AllData = html.fromhtml(data.d);

                 $("#home%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%").html(AllData);


            })
        });

});

</script>
```

I am getting error Like this:SyntaxError:
 identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

can you please advice why I am getting this type of error?